# I want to skip record if I am not able to parse it to Long

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using this code snippet

```
val profSalData: RDD[(String, AnyVal)] = data.map[(String, AnyVal)](f =>
      {
        (
          f.split("\\|")(3),
          util.control.Exception.ignoring(
            classOf[NumberFormatException],
            classOf[ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException]) { f.split("\\|")(4).toLong } match {
            case p: Exception.Catch[Unit] => 
            case c => c

          })
      })
```

input and ouput

```
803|70|M|administrator|34105
74|39|M|scientist|T8H1N
74|39|M|scientist|
74|39|M|scientist|12345

(administrator,34105)
(scientist,())
(scientist,())
(scientist,12345)
```

i want ignore blank and  non parsable to long, from output.
I can use filter but do not want use filter here like below

```
.filter(f => { f._2.toString() != "()" })
```

Comment: are you using RDD or DataFrame ?

Comment: I am using RDD.

Answer (score 0):

You can try PartialFunction.
For example, I want to get only Int type data from: List(1, "abc")
You can write some partial function like:

```
 def getIntData(list: List[Any]): List[Int] = {
   list.collect{
      case data:Int => data
   }
}
```

To know more about the partial function: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/PartialFunction.html